# Show video metadata in Windows 10 volume control overlay

Tags: javascript, html, web, media

I'm setting up my own media server, complete with a custom website (made by me). What I'm trying to implement is the YouTube-like media metadata on the Windows 10 volume overlay. For those who don't know, it looks like this: [image: YouTube media metadata on volume control overlay]

I did some experimenting (in Chrome at least), and found that the page title seems to show on non-YouTube websites playing media. Is there an API that does this? If so, is there an equivalent on other browsers (Firefox, Opera, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with the [MediaSession API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession).  Something like this:

```
navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
  title: 'All Star',
  artist: 'Smash Mouth',
  album: 'Astrolounge',
  artwork: [{src: 'cover.jpg'}]
});
```